# Remove hyphens while search time in ElasticSearch

Tags: java, spring-boot, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

I want to create a search for books with ElasticSearch and SpringData.

I index my books with ISBN/EAN without hyphens and save it in my database. This data I index with ElasticSearch.

Indexed data: 1113333444444
If I'm search for a ISBN/EAN with hyphen: 111-3333-444444

There is no result. If I'm searching without hyphen, my book will be found as expected.

My settings are like this:

```
{
  "analysis": {
    "filter": {
      "clean_special": {
        "type": "pattern_replace",
        "pattern": "[^a-zA-Z0-9]",
        "replacement": ""
      }
    },
    "analyzer": {
      "isbn_search_analyzer": {
        "type": "custom",
        "tokenizer": "keyword",
        "filter": [
          "clean_special"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I index my fields like this:

```
   @Field(type = FieldType.Keyword, searchAnalyzer = "isbn_search_analyzer")
   private String isbn;
   @Field(type = FieldType.Keyword, searchAnalyzer = "isbn_search_analyzer")
   private String ean;
```

If I test my analyzer:

```
GET indexname/_analyze
{
  "analyzer" : "isbn_search_analyzer",
  "text" : "111-3333-444444"
}
```

I get following result:

```
{
  "tokens" : [
    {
      "token" : "1113333444444",
      "start_offset" : 0,
      "end_offset" : 15,
      "type" : "word",
      "position" : 0
    }
  ]
}
```

If I'm search like this:

```
GET indexname/_search
{
   "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "fields": [ "isbn", "ean" ],
      "query": "111-3333-444444"
    }
  }
}
```

I don't get any result. Have someone of you an idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Elasticsearch does not analyze fields of type `keyword`.  You need to set the type to `text`.

Comment: Before it was "text", but it didn't work either. I have the feeling that the FieldMapping is ignored.

Comment: Is the mapping created by Spring Data Elasticsearch? Spring Data Elasticsearch only autmatically writes the mapping for a repository if the index does not already exist. Or if you explicitly use `IndexOperations.putMapping()`

Comment: I think Spring Data do it automatically but I don't know why. I added the `@Field` Annotation first and now I tried it with a mapping.json and `@Mapping` Annotation. 
I create the index manually and had called the `putMapping()` method and removed this statement. But there is no difference.

Comment: in the `@Field` use you show, you specify a `searchAnalyzer`, but not the analyzer to use during indexing. So when storing data, the default analyzer will be used, splitting the ISBN into tokens, and on search you expect it without hyphens.

Comment: My Input ISBN is without hyphens because I remove this before I stored this data into ElasticSearch. So the only thing, what ElasticSearch receive is a text. But I added an index_analyzer as well and there was no difference. 
If I open Kibana and check the mapping: Every Field is type text and also keyword. 
ean: Text
ean.keyword: Keyword
isbn: Text
isbn.keyword: Keyword 
No matter what I specify as mapping

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by @P.J.Meisch, you have done everything correct, but missed defining your field data type to `text`, when you define them as `keyword`, even though you are explicitly telling ElasticSearch to use your custom-analyzer `isbn_search_analyzer`, it will be ignored.

Working example on your sample data when field is defined as `text`.

**Index mapping**

```
{
    "settings": {
        "analysis": {
            "filter": {
                "clean_special": {
                    "type": "pattern_replace",
                    "pattern": "[^a-zA-Z0-9]",
                    "replacement": ""
                }
            },
            "analyzer": {
                "isbn_search_analyzer": {
                    "type": "custom",
                    "tokenizer": "keyword",
                    "filter": [
                        "clean_special"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "mappings": {
        "properties": {
            "isbn": {
                "type": "text",
                "analyzer": "isbn_search_analyzer"
            },
            "ean": {
                "type": "text",
                "analyzer": "isbn_search_analyzer"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Index Sample records**

```
{
    "isbn" : "111-3333-444444"
}

{
    "isbn" : "111-3333-2222"
}
```

**Search query**

```
{
    "query": {
        "query_string": {
            "fields": [
                "isbn",
                "ean"
            ],
            "query": "111-3333-444444"
        }
    }
}
```

**And search response**

```
"hits": [
            {
                "_index": "65780647",
                "_type": "_doc",
                "_id": "1",
                "_score": 0.6931471,
                "_source": {
                    "isbn": "111-3333-444444"
                }
            }
        ]
```

Comment: Before it was "text", but it didn't work either. I have the feeling that the FieldMapping is ignored.